# How do I change costumes?

Tags: shovel-knight-pocket-dungeon

There is a mysterious costume salesperson at camp named Myriad who sold me costumes for 1000 gold each. However, I can't find a way to see the costumes I've bought, let alone equip them.

How do I change costumes?

[image: buying an outfit from Myriad]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right below the costume salesman, there's a pile of junk (costumes?) that gets bigger with each purchase. Bump into the pile to cycle through costumes.

Source, [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ShovelKnight/comments/rgniz9/how_do_you_change_costumes_pocket_dungeon/).